# Name of es6 module 'module' is equivalent to 'Module'?

Tags: javascript

```
// a.js

export const a = 'a';

// A.js

export const A = 'A';

// index.js

import {a} from './a';
import {A} from './A';
```

javascript is allowed to create es6 modules differing only in letter case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends much on your module loader/bundler and file system.

ES6 considers these as two **different** module specifiers for sure. It's *possible* that they resolve to the same module, but unlikely.

In any case, I would recommend to stay away from this, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot the OP may have a different bundler, I just assumed the ES6 module system. Which bundlers, do you know, aren't case-sensitive for module identifiers?

Comment: Also, I would assume it depends on the file system. If the file system is not case-sensitive, having both the `a.js` and `A.js` in the same folder would not be possible.

Comment: @AndrewLi There is no "*the* ES6 module system", everyone can write his own module name resolver. I don't know of any existing (and believe it would be pretty stupid), but it's *possible* - and of course there are case-insensitive file systems (though rare) where it's a necessity. It's also possible (and not so stupid) that a resolver would throw exceptions or at least emit warnings on two too-similar-named files.

Comment: @Bergi Wouldn't the module system from the spec be called *the ES6 module system* though, and complying implementations? That would distinguish from filenames right (on case-sensitive systems)?

Comment: @AndrewLi The spec distinguishes the module specifiers - they're just the literal strings basically. Whether those should be treated as equivalent and resolve to the same module or not, or whether they should have anything to do with *file* names at all, is not part of the spec.